# Spring boot Reactive app starts tomcat in place of Netty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot reactive application generated from spring starter. It should use the Netty server by default but I can see that the `tomcat has started on port 8080` in the console.

Below is my pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have choose some parts of `pom.xml` not entire pom.xml is included.

Below is the class for Spring-boot main app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFlux
public class SpringWebFluxDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringWebFluxDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is there anything else missing ? I think it should boot up with Netty only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you want netty instead as explained in documentation [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html)

you've to exclude tomcat and include netty :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I am asking for Netty for reactive programming.

Comment: Ok so i guess the spring-boot-starter-data-rest is the only bringing tomcat

Comment: You will still need to follow the same procedure, just including the right dependency. "spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty"

Answer (score 2):

I have followed this

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

and I have excluded tomcat dependencies, rebuild the project. it was up and running on netty.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```